# Get rid of images, styling etc in PDF and only retain text? (Like removing .css from a webpage)

Tags: pdf, adobe-acrobat

So I have this massive manual from work that I want to print out but to save ink I want to remove all the unnecessary objects (pictures, background, fancy fonts etc) and have a black and white copy.

Kind of like removing the .css from a webpage and only leaving the structure behind.

Is there any way to go about this with Adobe Acrobat? Take note that I have quite a few data tables.

Any alternative software is fine. E.g. converting to another format.

Answer (score 1):

If you only want the text from the document, you could use Microsoft Word's 'paste special' feature:

1. Open the manual you want to copy
2. Select what you need (or do Ctrl+A to select the whole lot)
3. Open Word
4. Go Paste->Paste Special
5. Select "Unformatted text"
6. Click OK.

Comment: This is super cool!

Comment: @meiryo if this answered your question, could you please mark it as accepted? :)